# WindowSize error message when saving Graphics object as PNG

Tags: graphics, export, bugs

When I try to save a `Graphics` object using the menu File ▶ Save Selection As... or via right click and Save Graphic As... the Messages window pops up with the following error message:

```
The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.
```

Than I tried to use WindowSize, but I can't get any output if I add WindowSize to

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], 
  MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {tockez0, 10^(11) poljez0 + tockez0}]},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y,}]
```

Anything I can do? :/

I want to save it in any format that LaTeX can work with, I prefer .PNG